# Is there a way to trigger a Google Cloud Storage download object event?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Whenever an object is read/downloaded I want to trigger a Google Cloud Storage event to be listened by the Google Cloud functions to handle this event calling an auth endpoint to check if the user has access to the requested file, if so, the user receives the file.

Use case: When a user requests a stored file I want to first check if the user is allowed to download that specific file by calling an auth endpoint to authenticate and authorize the user access to the file. And only if he/she is allowed the file will be downloaded.

I've only found 4 event types supported by Google Cloud Storage Triggers: finalize, delete, archive and metadataUpdate.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#event_types

Comment: Could you expand on your use case? It seems like your are validating if the user has access to the file **after** is already read/downloaded, if the file was already read/downloaded is because the user had access to it.

Comment: I want to validate the user access to the file **before** downloading it. I added the use case in the question

Comment: How is this different from any existing IAM's attached to the GCS bucket to authenticate inbound request or even via Signed URL's to access files.

Comment: With IAM I would need to manage the user's access whenever something changes in our app. That's why I want to auth using our current user state.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I see now that you are only looking for a way to give access to the object to the user. As Raunak mentioned, Signed URL can be a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question: "Is there a way to trigger a Google Cloud Storage download object event?"

Basically you are asking how to "download" an object. But under your use case would be: How to let some user download an specific object.

A solution for that would a [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which can let you provide the user with an URL to download the object for a limited time. If you redirect the user directly to that URL the download would start immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `signed URL` which essentially can be attached to a file is a URL which permits access to private objects stored on GCS. It is a means of keeping objects secure, yet grant temporary access to a specific object. Note there is no concept of SIgned URL for a directory of files.

It is created via a `hash calculation` based on the object path, expiry time and a shared Secret Access Key belonging to an account that has permission to access the GCS object. As such, each signed URL is unique.

Essentially, anyone who has this signed URL can do any ops which this URL is allowed to do. The only way to secure this further in case of any breach would be to rotate signing keys or changing the signing keys.